# Use HTML entities in my <script> block in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-entities

I want to use the HTML-Symbols `&#9650` and `&#9660` that stand for "arrow up" and "arrow down" in the `<script>` section of my Vue.js component. I know that something simple as the following doesn't work. But I tried different functions that I found on the internet and nothing worked.

```
this.$refs["span-1"].textContent = "&#9650";
```

Comment: Try `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I wasted so much time on this.

Comment: I assume you are trying to toggle this arrow at some point. You already got your answer, but if I may suggest: Do those with CSS instead of using $refs. Usually, it is not a good practice to modify the HTML that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I could also do it with CSS. I want to change the content of the <span> with three different strings depending on what I click. What comes to my mind is that I need 3 different CSS classes to achieve that. Is there a simpler way? Is  $refs a better choice here and why is it not a good practice in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this **:**

1. Use `v-html` directive

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    content: "&#9650"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-html="content"></p>
</div>
```

2. Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.myTag.innerHTML = "&#9650";
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p ref="myTag"></p>
</div>
```